# Can we specify exact level for winston to log - only info level not error level?

Tags: winston

I have a logger of winston below. when I try to debug my app. However when I debug my logs, all my screen gets filled with 'error' level. All my useful logs I have put into 'info'. Is there a way that I can only checking only my 'info' level logs?

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            'timestamp': true,
            level: "info"
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this handy fork of winston (the downside is that it was forked 3 years ago and doesn't seem to be actively maintained any longer):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-levelonly

Alternatively, you can define a custom transport, like shown here:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/628

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it just requires a little more setup. Below is a configuration I use.

```
const levels = {
  error: 'error',
  warn: 'warn',
  info: 'info',
  http: 'http',
  debug: 'debug',
  critical: 'critical'
};

const logger = createLogger({
  levels: levels,
  format: combine(
    timestamp({
      format: 'YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    errors({ stack: true }),
    splat(),
    printf(
      ({ level, message, timestamp, ...metadata }) =>
        `${timestamp} [${level}] : ${message}} ${
          metadata ? JSON.stringify(metadata) : ''
        }`
    )
  ),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'api' },
  transports: [
    
 /**write all logs with an importance level of error, debug, http, and debug to 
 * their own files and all logs combined to api-all.log
 */
    new transports.File({ filename: 'api-error.log', level: levels.error }),
    new transports.File({filename: 'api-http.log', level: levels.http}),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'api-debug.log', level: levels.debug }),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'api-all.log', levels: levels }),
  ],
});

//
// If we're not in production then log to the `console` with the format:
// `${info.level}: ${info.message} JSON.stringify({ ...rest }) `
//
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  logger.add(
    new transports.Console({
      format: combine(colorize(), simple()),
    })
  );
}

module.exports.logger = logger;
module.exports.level = levels;
```

To log:

```
const {logger, level: logerLevels} = require('./logger');
logger.log(logerLevels.info, `Testing info.`)
logger.log(logerLevels.error, `Testing error`)
```

...

Note that when creating the logger with createLogger, we need to set the levels, not level. There is a property 'level' which if instantiated will set to a single level. Passing the levels object is a catchall, so that we will log ALL the levels. Also note the transports.File(...) you can set files for each level or ALL levels if you again set the 'levels' prop in the options. If we just set the 'level' prop, then we will get that level -- though winston does combine some levels by default.

You will also notice the custom print function. This just formats the output to make it a bit more readable as opposed to JSON format. The output will appear like so:

```
debug: Debug test {"service":"api","timestamp":"22-08-25 07:48:44"}
error: test error log {"service":"api","timestamp":"22-08-25 07:48:44"}
http: test http {"service":"api","timestamp":"22-08-25 07:48:44"}
info: test info {"service":"api","timestamp":"22-08-25 07:48:44"}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out logs by creating two or more loggers as per your requirement and adding name property to them. This worked for me.

```
const winston = require("winston");

const infoLogger = winston.createLogger({
  defaultMeta: { service: "log-service" },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      name: "info",
      filename: "./logs/info.log",
      level: "info",
    }),
  ],
});

const errorLogger = winston.createLogger({
  defaultMeta: { service: "log-service" },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      name: "error",
      filename: "./logs/error.log",
      level: "error",
    }),
  ],
});

const logger = {
  info: (params) => {
    return infoLogger.info(params);
  },
  error: (params) => {
    return errorLogger.error(params);
  },
};

logger.info("info 1"); // Will go to info.log
logger.error("error 1"); // Will go to error.log
logger.info("info 2"); // Will go to info.log
logger.error("error 2 "); // Will go to error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add to [Devanand Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9879855/devanand-sharma) response. If you need more complex logs (other than just a single string) you can add winston.format.combine to each logger and then allow for multiple parameters to pass through:

Example:

```
const errorLogger = winston.createLogger({
format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.splat(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.json(),
),
transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
        name: "error",
        filename: "logs/error.log",
        level: "error",
    }),
],
```

});

then allow multiple parameters:

```
export const logger = {
info: (...params) => {
    return infoLogger.info(...params);
},
error: (...params) => {
    return errorLogger.error(...params);
},
```

};

Then you can do things like:

```
logger.error("%O", err);
```