# How to setup multiple exclusive custom levels in winston?

Tags: logging, winston

I tried setting up multiple exclusive custom levels in `winston`. For instance, default `error` level will only log within transport defined for `error` level. However, transport for `info` will log `info` and `error`.

Is there an option like this?

Probably this is a duplicate question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215559/can-we-specify-exact-which-level-winston-to-log).

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your custom log levels and pass it to your transport

example:-

```
 //your custom levels 
    const debugLevel = {
      levels: {
        error: 0,
        custom: 1,
        custom2: 2,
        custom3: 3,
        custom4: 4,
      },
    };

    //create your custom logger and pass debuglevels to the transport
    const customLogger = createLogger({
      levels: debugLevel.levels,
      format: combine(
        label({ label: 'customLogger' }),
      ),
  transports: [
    new (transports.File)({
      level : 'custom4',
      filename: 'your Logger fileName path',
      json: true,
    }),
  ],

    });
```

the most important part now, you have to configure transport-level 
so if you set it as `custom4` it means it will log custom4 + custom3 +....+ error, I defined it as `custom4` to log all custom levels.

example:- 
**if we set level as custom3**

```
customLogger.custom4('message') ; //this will not be logged into a file 
customLogger.custom3('message') ; //this will be logged 
customLogger.custom2('message') ; //this will be logged 
customLogger.custom1('message') ; //this will be logged 
customLogger.error('message') ; //this will be logged
```

**if we set level as error**

```
customLogger.custom4('message') ; //this will not  
customLogger.custom3('message') ; //this will not
customLogger.custom2('message') ; //this will not 
customLogger.custom1('message') ; //this will not
customLogger.error('message') ; //only this will be logged
```